# Managing request in spring microservices with multiple instances of a single service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, microservices

I have a java project and I am trying to scale my project so want to spin up 3 instance of a single microservice.

But I have an issue

to explain

From UI when user logs in, every 10sec a api request(for the specific user) goes to backend which gives the status of spring batch job (either running or not running for a particular user who has logged in). This works fine with only 1 instance.

but when I have 3 instances (instance 1, 2 & 3) of the same application,

say
first request at 10sec goes to instance 1  and job is running for the logged in user - it returns job is running. - correct
second request at 20sec goes to instance 2, since no job is running in instance 2 (job is running in instance 1) it return no job is running - incorrect
third request at 30sec goes to instance 3, since no job is running in instance 3 (job is running in instance 3) it return no job is running - incorrect

How do I make sure to get "job is running" as the status till the job in instance 1 gets over.

I am using spring microservices

please help in on this

Thanks in advance

Need to get job is running till job finishes in instance 1 for the particular user, for every api request

Comment: I believe that I've answered your question below. Can you check and accept please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're using Spring Batch and its [in memory job repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/domain.html#jobrepository).

If you are wanting to scale, you should really use a separate database to keep the metadata of those jobs. As per this [example](https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-spring-batch).

Configure and deploy your database, add a dataSource, ensure that your jobRepository uses that dataSource. All servers will then return the same values.

If this cannot be achieved, you should at least ensure that your load balancer has [sticky sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/sticky-sessions.html) enabled.

Comment: can you please help in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74474983/sticky-session-loadbalancing-in-spring-microserviceshttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/74474983/sticky-session-loadbalancing-in-spring-microservices